# Determine the convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to determine the convergence of the series whose general term is :
$$U_n = \left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n\ge 2).$$

I tried to use the fact that for any $n\ge 2$,
$0<1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} <1$, thus $Σ U_n$ is of the form $Σr^n$ with $0<r<1$ (convergent geometric series).

But it seems weird since r depends on n...

How would you do it ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go like this:

$ U_n = e^{n*ln(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})} = e^{n*(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{2n}+o(\frac{1}{n}))} $

=> $ U_n = O(e^{-\sqrt{n}}) $

Then : $ e^{-\sqrt{n}} = o(\frac{1}{n^2}) $ , hence your series converges

Comment: Merci bien ! :)

Comment: Why is $$e^{-\sqrt{n}+n o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})} =e^{-\sqrt{n}} +o(e^{-\sqrt{n}}) ?$$  There are two big issues here, one being addition in powers is not addition of exponentials. Second and more important, using $o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ is the power cannot lead to $o(e^{-\sqrt{n}})$, since the minus is the key for the proof....

Comment: Sorry I had a problem because of the maintenance. I've edited my answer

Comment: I's a O($e^{-\sqrt{n}}$) sorry. But from this it's stands I think

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Prove that $f(x)=(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$ is increasing on $(1, \infty)$.

Since 
$$\lim_n  \left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^{\sqrt{n}+1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

it follows that 
$$ \left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^{\sqrt{n}+1} < \frac{1}{e}$$

Then 
$$\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^{n} < \left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^{n-1}=
\left(\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt  n} \right)^{\sqrt{n}+1} \right)^{\sqrt{n}-1} < \left( \frac{1}{e} \right)^{\sqrt{n}-1}$$

Now, this last series, while not geometric is easy to study,  just split the sum in sums of the form $\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}$ and use $k \leq \sqrt{n} < (k+1)$ to put it between two nice series.